# Leadership Ph.D alternative

Tags: phd, teaching, accreditation

(asking for a friend) I'm currently teaching at an undergraduate institution with a Masters in leadership. However, for accreditation purposes (and making the higher-ups happy) they want me to get a Ph.D.. I'm not interested in getting one, and honestly it won't help my courses. In short, are there any post-graduate alternatives to a Ph.D. in leadership that would satisfy accreditation statistics?

Comment: Are there some related areas where your institution needs more faculty?  You could get a complementary PhD.

Comment: What do the accreditation bodies accept? The question should be asked them first.

Comment: I don't think you can get a definitive answer to this question without looking into your specific accreditor's policies, but in any case I think "making the higher-ups happy" may be crucial regardless of accreditation, thanks to widely discussed statistics like "percentage of faculty with terminal degrees".  If a Ph.D. is the terminal degree in leadership, then you might be stuck.

Comment: _honestly it won't help my courses_ - How do you know?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wide range of choices in managerial education, in general, and in leadership education, in particular. Most universities' business schools offer various executive education programs, which range from *continuous education / professional development* programs, such as (hereafter, I am using Harvard University just as an example for some types of programs) [these](http://www.dce.harvard.edu/professional/topic/leadership-management-programs) smaler scale programs, to [comprehensive executive leadership programs](http://www.exed.hbs.edu/programs/Pages/comprehensive-leadership-programs.aspx). Executive leadership programs can be *general* as well as *industry-oriented*, such [this higher education-focused](https://www.gse.harvard.edu/ppe/programs/highered) or [this healthcare-focused](http://www.hbs.edu/healthcare/executive-education/Pages/default.aspx). Other leadership education options include more lightweight alternatives, such as relevant *MOOCs with certificates* (either single courses, or thematic tracks), *university certificate programs* (such as [this one at MIT](http://executive.mit.edu/article/mit-sloan-executive-certificate-in-management-and-leadership)) and relevant *educational programs* by think tanks (like [ones by Aspen Institute](http://www.aspeninstitute.org/leadership-programs-top)), non-profits (like [ones by Center for Creative Leadership](http://www.ccl.org/Leadership/index.aspx)) and similar organizations.

Comment: Are any of these options considered alternatives to a Ph.D.?

Comment: @Drecate: Absolutely. Those options are certainly **not equal** alternatives to a Ph.D. (which, _by definition_, can only be another Ph.D.). However, the OP did not ask about equal alternatives, but rather alternatives for the purposes of accreditation. If said accreditation would only accept Ph.D. credentials, the question would not make any sense at all. Therefore, I have mentioned options, all or, likely, some of which are assumed to be acceptable for accreditation purposes.